# Windows cmd batch file calculation

Tags: batch-file

I have this code which is to divide two numbers from user input. It should exit the program if the user enters the number 999 for either the first or the second number. And if the user enters 0 for the second number, then it should ask the user to enter a non zero number. My problem is that when I enter two good numbers, I don't get any output. It just shows "Press any key to continue..." and then exits the whole terminal once I press any key. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
:MAIN
cls
echo.
SET /p num1="Please enter the first number: "
if %num1%==999 GOTO EOF
cls

:SECOND_NUM
SET /p num2="Please enter the second number: "
if %num2%==999 GOTO EOF
if %num2%==0 GOTO ERROR
echo.
GOTO DIVISION

:DIVISION
SET /A result = %num1% / %num2%
echo The answer of %num1% divided by %num2% = %result% >> results.txt
pause
exit
GOTO CONTINUE



:ERROR
echo Error! Cannot divide by 0 (zero). Enter a non zero second number, please.
GOTO SECOND_NUM


:CONTINUE
echo To Exit the program, please enter 999
GOTO MAIN
echo.
pause 
EXIT
```

Comment: It's because the output is redirected to *results.txt*.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a couple of things especially in these sections.

```
:MAIN
cls
echo.
SET /p num1="Please enter the first number: "
if %num1%==999 GOTO EOF
cls

:SECOND_NUM
SET /p num2="Please enter the second number: "
if %num2%==999 GOTO EOF
if %num2%==0 GOTO ERROR
echo.
GOTO DIVISION

:DIVISION
SET /A result = %num1% / %num2%
echo The answer of %num1% divided by %num2% = %result% >> results.txt
pause
exit
GOTO CONTINUE
```

Now in these `%num2%==999 GOTO EOF` I believe the proper way to exit the batch file with the End Of File GOTO is `GOTO :EOF`, notice the semicolon. Otherwise it'll say something like couldn't find the path, and it'll exit anyways. Here, `echo The answer of %num1% divided by %num2% = %result% >> results.txt` all you're telling the batch file to do is to redirect the output to the results.txt by `>> results.txt`, so if you wanted to display the text, just remove that little chunk. and finally, right after the pause, where you're wanting to display the calculation, before you tell the file where to goto, you included an `exit` so the batch file exits.

---

**Edit**
Here's how I would do your entire batch file. I moved a few things around, got rid of some, added some.

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 0A

:CONTINUE
CLS
ECHO.
SET /P X=Do you wish to divide? [Y/N] 
IF /I %X% EQU Y (GOTO :MAIN) ELSE (GOTO :EOF)

:MAIN
CLS
ECHO.
SET /p num1="Please enter the first number: "

:SECOND_NUM
CLS
ECHO.
SET /p num2="Please enter the second number: "
IF "%num2%" EQU "0" GOTO :ERROR

:DIVISION
CLS
ECHO.
SET /A result=%num1% / %num2%
ECHO The answer of %num1% divided by %num2% = %result%
ECHO The result of %num1% divided by %num2% = %result% >> results.txt
PAUSE
GOTO :CONTINUE

:ERROR
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO Error! Cannot divide by 0 (zero). Enter a non zero second number, please.
PAUSE
GOTO :SECOND_NUM
```

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot. I have a question, Is there a way to inform the user "To enter 999 to exit the program" and then once the user enters 999 it exits the program but if not, it starts all over again. I tried with the :CONTINUE function, like `:CONTINUE`
`SET /I input="To Exit the program, please enter 999"`
`if %input%==999 GOTO :EOF`
`GOTO MAIN`
`echo.`
`pause`
`EXIT`

Comment: I get an error message saying
**The syntax of the command is incorrect**                                                                                            
**GOTO was unexpected at this time**

Comment: @Truecolor, I edited my answer for you, that should solve any issues. I personally wouldn't have an exit method in the form of numbers, in a calculator, just in the off chance I wanted to divide something by 999, than I'd be in a pickle. Hopefully my edited answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your code looks much cleaner than mine. It is just that I have to use the 999 option for my assignment.